# Error creating bean entityManagerFactory: SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Springboot version 3.1.0 with Hibernate version 6.1.0 and jakarta persistence api 3.1.0.

I'm using PostgresSQL.

When I run the code it creates the mitarbeiter and inserts the rows that I give him, but I have the following error: "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider", caused by "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider"

**application-local.yaml** looks like this:

```
com:
  example:
    cors:
      allowed-origins:
        - "http://localhost:8080"
        - "http://localhost:4200"

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?useSSL=false
    username: postgres
    password:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    enabled: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-jpa-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ElasticSearch-Anbindung per Hibernate Search -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OpenAPI / Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT Authentication -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Liquibase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Datenbank-Treiber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Passwortqualitätsprüfungen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
            <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Export nach Word -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docx4j-samples-resources</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>20200713.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Microsoft Graph API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaX Mail / Activation-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Mitarbeiter.java**:

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.search.mapper.pojo.mapping.definition.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "mitarbeiter")
public class Mitarbeiter {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mitarbeiterSeqGen")
  @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "mitarbeiter_seq", name = "mitarbeiterSeqGen",
      allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "mitarbeiter_id")
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
  @KeywordField
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "vorname")
  @FullTextField(analyzer = "german")
  private String vorname;

  @Column(name = "nachname")
  @FullTextField(analyzer = "german")
  private String nachname;

  public Mitarbeiter(Long id, String vorname, String nachname) {
    this.id = id;
    this.vorname = vorname;
    this.nachname = nachname;

  }
}
```

AccessingDataJpaApplication.java:

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
    }}
```

**Detailed error**:

```
2023-10-20T09:30:09.235+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Starting AccessingDataJpaApplication using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 18304 (C:\Profilmanager\gs-accessing-data-jpa\complete\target\classes started by VladSuciu in C:\Profilmanager\gs-accessing-data-jpa\complete)
2023-10-20T09:30:09.241+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "local"
2023-10-20T09:30:10.642+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-20T09:30:10.704+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 49 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-20T09:30:11.906+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-20T09:30:11.919+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-20T09:30:11.919+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-10-20T09:30:12.083+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-20T09:30:12.086+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2778 ms
2023-10-20T09:30:12.481+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-20T09:30:12.822+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@55222ee9
2023-10-20T09:30:12.823+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:12.989+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to public
2023-10-20T09:30:13.407+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.415+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.421+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.426+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.434+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.437+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2023-10-20T09:30:13.464+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Creating database history table with name: public.databasechangelog
2023-10-20T09:30:13.474+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.479+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading from public.databasechangelog
2023-10-20T09:30:13.482+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.486+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
Running Changeset: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::1::
2023-10-20T09:30:13.531+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Sequence mitarbeiter_seq created
2023-10-20T09:30:13.534+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::1:: ran successfully in 9ms
2023-10-20T09:30:13.538+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.540+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
Running Changeset: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::2::
2023-10-20T09:30:13.554+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Table mitarbeiter created
2023-10-20T09:30:13.557+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::2:: ran successfully in 15ms
2023-10-20T09:30:13.559+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
Running Changeset: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::3::
2023-10-20T09:30:13.573+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Unique constraint added to mitarbeiter(email)
2023-10-20T09:30:13.577+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00001-initial-database.yaml::3::ran successfully in 15ms
2023-10-20T09:30:13.579+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
Running Changeset: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00006-initial-data-mitarbeiter.yaml::1::
2023-10-20T09:30:13.588+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : New row inserted into mitarbeiter
2023-10-20T09:30:13.591+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00006-initial-data-mitarbeiter.yaml::1:: ran successfully in 9ms
2023-10-20T09:30:13.594+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
Running Changeset: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00006-initial-data-mitarbeiter.yaml::2:
2023-10-20T09:30:13.603+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : New row inserted into mitarbeiter
2023-10-20T09:30:13.607+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : ChangeSet classpath*:db/changelog/changes/00006-initial-data-mitarbeiter.yaml::2::ran successfully in 8ms
2023-10-20T09:30:13.610+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.613+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase                                : Update command completed successfully.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.619+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.executor                       : Changelog query completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.623+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
2023-10-20T09:30:13.755+03:00  WARN 18304 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
2023-10-20T09:30:13.756+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-10-20T09:30:13.764+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.772+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-10-20T09:30:13.790+03:00  INFO 18304 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-20T09:30:13.831+03:00 ERROR 18304 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.example.accessingdatajpa.AccessingDataJpaApplication.main(AccessingDataJpaApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider does not implement the requested interface jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have way to much (and conflicting) dependencies, you are trying to outsmart Spring Boot dependency management, tip don't do that. Remove the `javax.mail` and `javax.activation` dependencies, those are incompatible, remove the `hibernate-core` and `jakarta.persistence` dependency that is already included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Remove the version for the various `spring-boot-starter-` dependencies that have it, remove `jackson-datatype-jsr310` and `jakarta.servlet` as well. There are probably more as you have the `javax.persistence` import instead of `jakarta.persistence`.

Comment: Made all those changes, still inserts the row in the db, but now I get a different error: `"Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]. Caused by .ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect]. Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service JdbcEnvironment due to: Unable to resolve name PostgreSQL9Dialect as strategy org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect`

Comment: Because that class doesn't exist anymore. Are "following" some tutorial and decided to use newer dependencies? Use `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` instead.